# suitable regression methodology for small data with many features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, prediction

I have a dataset of about 100 samples. Each sample also has about 30 features.
I am currently observing a relationship with a variable or y through EDA.
Are there any machine learning algorithms or general processes that would recommend such small data and many features?

Comment: Is there a linear relationship between the features and the target variable?

Comment: thank you for your comment. Some features may seem like linear relationship, but they are not noticeable.